# How to comment out a parent xml tag with a specific child tag using sed?

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have a xml file something like the one shown below. If `<name>` is **xyz**, the whole parent `<types>` should be commented out. How can I use sed to achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="test">
    <types>
        <name>abc</name>
        <members>abc_member_1</members>
        <members>abc_member_2</members>
    </types>
    <types>
        <name>def</name>
        <members>def_member_1</members>
        <members>def_member_2</members>
        <members>def_member_3</members>
    </types>
    <types>
        <name>xyz</name>
        <members>xyz_member_1</members>
    </types>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <fullName>test</fullName>
<Package>
```

I have tried using this and it works for a single line only.

```
sed -i -e '/xyz/s/\(^.*$\)/<!--\1-->/' ./sample.xml
    rm -rf ./sample.xml-e
```

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT for this kind of thing?  Could be a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with the warning that your namespace URI is not absolute, you can use the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet (after fixing your `</Package>` end tag).

It just uses the *identity template* in combination with a template to use the (not by all XSLT processors supported) `disable-output-escaping="yes"` option to comment-out the relevant `<types>` element. The formally correct way would have been using the `<xsl:comment>` element, but unfortunately it doesn't support an element tree as sub-element (only text nodes). So the *hack* with the `disable-output-escaping` *is the only choice in this case*.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tst="test">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Identity template --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="tst:types[tst:name='xyz']">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Final note:**
It is *always* better to use an XSLT processor like `xsltproc` to handle XML files than using `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score -1):

If you can not use a better tools, this `gnu awk` may do:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /name.xyz/ {s=NR-1} s && /<\/types>/ {e=NR} END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print i>=s&&i<=e?"#"a[i]:a[i]}' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="test">
    <types>
        <name>abc</name>
        <members>abc_member_1</members>
        <members>abc_member_2</members>
    </types>
    <types>
        <name>def</name>
        <members>def_member_1</members>
        <members>def_member_2</members>
        <members>def_member_3</members>
    </types>
#    <types>
#        <name>xyz</name>
#        <members>xyz_member_1</members>
#    </types>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <fullName>test</fullName>
<Package>
```